# Changing API level Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, android-api-levels

I want to change the minimum SDK version in Android Studio from API 12 to API 14. I have tried changing it in the manifest file, i.e.,

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
```

and rebuilding the project, but I still get the Android Studio IDE throwing up some errors. I presume I have to set the min SDK in 'project properties' or something similar so the IDE recognizes the change, but I can't find where this is done in Android Studio.

Comment: what is that some errors? we can't help you without logcat

Comment: They aren't compilation errors. It is the IDE giving a red underline when I'm trying to use `GridLayout' in the layout xml, i.e., telling me that a minimum API level 14 is required. Therefore, there must be somewhere in Android Studio where you can set the minimum API level after you have created the project. I have seen similar posts for Eclipse, but not for Android Studio.

Comment: Have you instaled the API level 14 SDK package?

Comment: If I start a new project and select API level 14 from the outset I have no problem developing in Android Studio, i.e., I must have API Level 14 SDK installed. However, if I simply want to update an existing project to use API 14 as minimum, I can't work out where in the Android Studio GUI IDE that I tell it to do this.

Comment: Post your `Logcat`. and to change the `MinSDKVersion` this is the very simplest solution which u have already tried.. i.e.change in `Manifest`

Comment: seems like this is a bug from Android Studio

Comment: You can update your API via wizard, see this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21449947/how-do-i-set-the-minimum-api-level-for-projects-in-android-studio/25481715#25481715

Comment: @ArashGM Logcat is unnecessary, it has nothing to do with what he's asking, he's just asking how to change the API, not about the errors. (This was after the post was edited)

Answer (score 667, accepted):

When you want to update your minSdkVersion in an existing Android project...

1. **Update `build.gradle (Module: YourProject)`** under **Gradle Script** and
   make sure that it is **NOT** `build.gradle (Project: YourProject.app)`.

An example of build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion "28.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.stackoverflow.answer"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

dependencies {
    androidTestCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

2. **Sync gradle button** (refresh all gradle projects also works).

[image]
or
[image]

3. **Rebuild project**

**After** updating the *build.gradle*'s `minSdkVersion`, you have to click on the button to sync gradle file ("Sync Project with Gradle files"). That will clear the marker.

Updating *manifest.xml*, for e.g. deleting any references to SDK levels in the manifest file, is NOT necessary anymore in Android Studio.

Comment: My project's build.gradle is empty?  What is the syntax to update? --- Ooops, there are two build.gradle files.  I found the one in -> src has the versions, etc.

Comment: Using this advice, I managed to get things to sync, but I had to EXIT Android Studio before the compile was error free.  I performed many little steps, so I don't know what was really the necessary step.

Comment: why have they made it such a ball ache? seem to remember in eclipse I only had to do this in one place...

Comment: @DeanWild In Android Studio is as well in one place. Forget about API levels in the manifest file.

Comment: Is it possible to make it use the manifest instead? Also, is it possible to make it always use the latest build-tools that are available?

Comment: As of now, you can find two build.gradle inside Gradle Scripts folder, I needed to go for the one having Module:app.

Comment: @androiddeveloper Gradle overrides the manifest, so just delete it from the gradle file and add it to your manifest file. I DO NOT recommend this tho, Gradle is the way to go and there are reasons why they went from manifest to gradle.

Comment: @Sotti Thank you. Didn't know this. What's the benefit of putting it on the gradle file?

Comment: @Quantumdroid That is because you are using the Android view. I don't like that view and don't use it.

Comment: For beginners in Android Studio "Sync gradle button" is located in `Tools -> Android -> Sync Project with Gradle Files`
"Rebuild project" `Build -> Rebuild Project`

Comment: ... but then you need to build a signed APK to upload to Google Play. And chances are you get a "njet" message. Certain features that have become (an often) integral part of your application will prevent a "down-grade" of your min SDK. So, think twice about you min SDK wen starting a new project.

Comment: I found in the current version of Android Studio, the _Sync Project with Gradle Files_ is an option in the _File_ menu

Answer (score 205):

Update **2022**

For Android Studio users:

1. Right click the **App** directory and
   Choose the "**Open Module Settings**" (F4) option
   [image: Right click App then choose Open Module Settings]
2. Change the "**Min SDK Version**" in the **Default Config** tab
   [image: Choose Min SDK Version]
   NOTE:
   You might also want to change;
   the "**Target SDK Version**" in the **Default Config** tab and
   the "**Compile SDK Version**" in the **Properties** tab
   [image: Choose Compile SDK Version]
3. Click **Apply**, then **OK**, and Gradle should automatically be synced

---

For users of older Android Studio versions:

1. Right click the **App** directory and
   Choose the "**Module Setting**" (F4) option
2. Change the **ADK Platform** to what you need
3. Click **OK** and Gradle should automatically be synced

Comment: The above solution given is, to me, the best way to go.  Let the tool do all the necessary changes iso you yourself fiddling with different files, taking the risk of screwing things or forgetting important details.

Comment: This doesn't work in Studio 0.8.2. You can change settings and press aplly, but studio ignore this.<br/>

Solution:
- Close Android Studio
- Edit "/app/build.gradle"
- change SDK-MinVersion entry
- restart Android Studio

Gradle syncs automatically

Comment: In Studio 1.4 you need to look in the "Flavors" tab. See priyankvex's answer.

Comment: In Studio 3.5, you need to click the "Default Config" tab. Flavors tab doesn't appear to exist any more.

Answer (score 142):

As now Android Studio is stable, there is an easy way to do it.

1. Right click on your project file
2. Select "Open Module Settings"
3. Go to the "Flavors" tab.

[image]

4. Select the Min SDK Version from the drop down list

**PS:** Though this question was already answered but Android Studio has changed a little bit by its stable release. So an easy straight forward way will help any new answer seeker landing here.

Comment: Editing the gradle files didn't work for me, but this did. Thanks!

Comment: This has changed again:  The "Flavors" tab is no more.  Instead, on step 3, in the Project Settings area click Modules then use the Project Level drop down box to select the API version.   This isn't the same as setting the min API version, but rather the version which will be used to build the app.

Comment: I only get api 23 in the dropdown... I need api 10

Comment: little bit? this fking IDE changes a lot between versions causing a lot of breaks in running old code. Very very pathetic compared to the legacy of backward compatibility that is exemplified by Microsoft.

Comment: Accepted answer and the second most "accepted" answer didn't work for me, lots of errors on build, this is the right solution for me! thanks

Answer (score 10):

In android studio you can easily press:

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>.
2. If you have a newer version of `android studio`, then press on app first.
   Then, continue with step three as follows.
3. A window will open with a bunch of options
4. Go to **Flavors** and that's actually all you need

You can also change the `versionCode` of your app there.

Answer (score 6):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20002844/991903), you just  don't include minsdkversion in the manifest.xml, and the build system will use the values from the build.gradle file and put the information into the final apk.

Because the build system needs this information anyway, this makes sense. You should not need to define this values two times.

You just have to sync the project after changing the `build.gradle` file, but Android Studio 0.5.2 display a yellow status bar on top of the build.gradle editor window to help you

Also note there at least two `build.gradle` files: one master and one for the app/module. The one to change is in the app/module, it already includes a property `minSdkVersion` in a newly generated project.

Answer (score 6):

In `build.gradle` change `minSdkVersion 13` to `minSdkVersion 8` Thats all you need to do. I solved my problem by only doing this.

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.sabrim.sbrtest"
    minSdkVersion 8
    targetSdkVersion 20
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
```

Answer (score 6):

For the latest Android Studio v2.3.3 (October 11th, 2017) :
 1. Click `View` on menu bar 
 2. Click Open Module Settings 
 3. Open `Flavors` tab 
 4. Choose Min `Sdk` version you need 
 [image: IDE Project Structure Window]
 6. Click OK

Answer (score 5):

If you're having troubles specifying the SDK target to Google APIs instead of the base Platform SDK just change the `compileSdkVersion 19` to `compileSdkVersion "Google Inc.:Google APIs:19"`

Answer (score 4):

As well as updating the manifest, update the module's `build.gradle` file too (it's listed in the project pane just below the manifest - if there's no `minSdkVersion` key in it, you're looking at the wrong one, as there's a couple). A rebuild and things should be fine...

Answer (score 3):

In Android studio open build.gradle and edit the following section:

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.demo.myanswer"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
```

here you can change minSdkVersion from 12 to 14

Answer (score 3):

File>Project Structure>Modules 
you can change it from there

Answer (score 3):

When you want to change minimum SDK you should take care of `minSdkVersion`[<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47269079/4770877) in **module** `build.garadle`

```
android {
  defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 21
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To change the minimum SDK version in Android Studio just...

1). Right click on "**app**" in the "Project" panel and choose "**Open Module Settings**"

[image: Right click on "app"]

2). Select the new "**Min SDK Version**" on the "**Default Config**" tab

[image: Choose the new "Min SDK Version" on the "Default Config" tab]

3). Click on "**OK**" and the project will now resync with the new Gradle settings.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the minSdkVersion in the manifest is not necessary. If you change it in the gradle build file, as seen below, you accomplish what you need to do.

```
defaultConfig {
   applicationId "com.demo.myanswer"
   minSdkVersion 14
   targetSdkVersion 23
   versionCode 1
   versionName "1.0"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For me what worked was: (right click)project->android tools->clear lint markers. Although for some reason the Manifest reverted to the old (lower) minimum API level, but after I changed it back to the new (higher) API level there was no red error underline and the project now uses the new minimum API level.

Edit: Sorry, I see you were using Android Studio, not Eclipse. But I guess there is a similar 'clear lint markers' in Studio somewhere and it might solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Gradle Scripts ->
build.gradle (Module: app) ->
`minSdkVersion (Your min sdk version)`

Answer (score 0):

New Android SDK Upgrade Assistant

> Starting with Android Studio Giraffe, see the steps required to
> upgrade the targetSdkVersion, or the API level that your app targets,
> directly in the Studio IDE. The Android SDK Upgrade Assistant pulls
> documentation directly into its tool window, so you don't have to jump
> back and forth between your browser and the IDE.

To open the Android SDK Upgrade Assistant, go to `Tools > Android SDK Upgrade Assistant`. In the Assistant panel, select the API level that you want to upgrade to for guidance. For the best experience, you should upgrade `targetSdkVersion` values one level at a time.

[image]