# How do I set the minimum api level for projects in Android Studio?

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio

I recently migrated a project into Android Studio 0.4.3.
When compiling, it gave me errors on several lines of java, including the following:

```
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();

fm.findFragmentById()

@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

getResources().getStringArray(R.array.course_descriptions);
```

I see the following error message:

```
Call requires API level 11 (current min is 7)
```

I'm running Android Studio .0.4.3. I also downloaded Android 4.4.2 (API 19) through the SDK manager.

I added the following line to my manifest:

```
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="14"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
```

I did a "Sync Project with Gradle files", cleaned and rebuilt the project.
I still see the same errors.

How do I fix this issue ?

Comment: Hi, I think you are compiling with another version of android (not 19). If you are on eclipse you can try in proyect properties, android libraries, check there that are the correct API 19. Regards.

Comment: I just found something interesting. A bug was captured by Studio:
`java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 20
 at org.jetbrains.android.dom.converters.ApiVersionConverter.getApiLevelLabel(ApiVersionConverter.java:57)
`

Answer (score 34):

I have 0.8.6 version and it's can be done like this:

In the menu: File -> Project Structure.

In the open menu, navigate to `app`, then in the tabs choose `Flavors`.

[image]

Comment: In android Studio 1.2.2: After the changes you propose you should run **Sync Project with Gradle files** (the icon-button located somewhere right from **Run** icon in Toolbar) in order to apply the changes

Answer (score 17):

If you have generated your project on recent versions of Android Studio, the setting is in gradle config file. Find `build.gradle` file in your application module. There should be something like this.

```
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 7
    targetSdkVersion 19
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Starting from gradle build system all your setting related to sdk and compilation APIs will be overridden by what you define in your `build.gradle` file.

So going forward if you want you can remove these all configurations from your **`AndroidManifest.xml`** and keep them in `build.gradle` files only to avoid confusions.

So check `minSdkVersion` in module's `build.gradle` file which is throwing the error.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '19.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 7      // Change 7 to 11 will solve your problem
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }

}
```

I prefer to have these all configurations in my top project level `build.gradle` file because if the configurations are different in different modules you will be ended up with Manifest Merging error.

Answer (score 2):

In the latest version as of dated 2020, perform the following steps:

1. Click on Files (top left)
2. Go to Project Structure (Ctlr + Alt + Shift + S)
3. Click on modules
4. In the right pane, click on Default Config (Middle one)
5. Change Minimum SDK version
6. Apply and click OK

Done!

Answer (score 1):

**Full app/build.gradle  minSdkVersion, targetSdkVersion**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.yourapp.package"
    minSdkVersion 18
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

packagingOptions {
    exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
}
}

dependencies {
androidTestCompile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
androidTestCompile('com.squareup.assertj:assertj-android:1.0.0'){
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module:'support-annotations'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply follow the steps (For android studio users):

1. right click the App directory
2. choose the "module setting" option
3. change the ADK Platform as what you need
4. Click Apply

That's all buddy, The gradle will rebuild the project automatically.