# Wrong Android version can I launch it?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have a problem, but I dont know how to solve it. I create a project for android 6.0 can I launch my prj on android 4.2.1? I am sorry for that kind of stupid question. [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the minSdk to 17 or below. See the answer below on how to do this.

[How do I set the minimum api level for projects in Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21449947/how-do-i-set-the-minimum-api-level-for-projects-in-android-studio)

Answer (score 1):

Go to "android manifest" and change there the "Min sdk" version to 17

Answer (score 1):

Change minSdkVersin in gradle.

[image]