# Doesnt recognise LayoutInflater

Tags: android

i gotten the error code, LayoutInflater cannot resolve the symbol.
It recommend me the use of LayoutInflaterCompat (android.support.v4.view) instead. Have tried looking at my manifest to set the min API Level via going to the build.gradle but it still recommend me a helper for lower version.

[How do I set the minimum api level for projects in Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21449947/how-do-i-set-the-minimum-api-level-for-projects-in-android-studio)

Comment: You should add AppCompat to your **gradle** file. ( it's not related to your manifest )

Comment: Hi, adding idea how to do that?
is this the one?
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CG_HxvV44zM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to android developer page, look for its library and manually key import android.view.LayoutInflater;
case closed. example of auto correct function failing.