# How to develop for Android on a 32 bit Linux

Tags: android, linux, cordova, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

The title of the question is the best I could give it, and that is exactly what I want to do: to develop Android apps on a 32 bit Linux (specifically, 32 bit Ubuntu, running moderately latest kernel 4.4.0-66-generic; 3G RAM).

What I have learnt/tried so far:

1. Android SDK stopped supporting dev on 32 bit Linux OS since >23
   upwards
2. For Android Studio, I can't get around appcompat so that I can build for lower version of android (e.g. version 19) because in the face of no option/instruction/clear directive, I changed `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25` to `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19` so I wasn't surprised when I got the error that `appcomat could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19`
3. At that stage, a notice popped up in Android Studio that I do not need appcompat for sdk version > 19 and build tools < 21 (or something like that) and then I removed `com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19` then the next error is `failed to resolve com.android.support:design:19`
4. I tried googling for any instruction/process guide specifically directed at developing Android apps on 32 bit Linux but find ***none***!
5. I tried Cordova but stuck at gradle build (maybe it is still because of the same issue above: android-sdk not supporting dev on ***32 bit Linux***) since Cordova still depends on android-sdk

From my google-wandering I stumbled on Cordova, and I love it (maybe because it is CLI-based and that I can see/control everything, it even has a *--verbose* option that shows all that is happening under the hood) but after reading several other articles I pieced together to get it to build on my 32 bit Linux, I still got stuck at the build stage because when the build process reaches the gradle stage, it stubbornly insists on using build-tools 25.0.2, and with all the articles I pieced together about how to set the build-tool version, I just couldn't get any way to persuade gradle to use the build-tools 19 that I already have fully installed (using the Android SDK Manager). To make gradle work for me, I have tried setting `<preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="19"/>` in config.xml and even set `cdvBuildToolsVersion=19` in `~/project_folder/platforms/android/gradle.properties` yet with all these efforts in Cordova I get rewarded with:

> Execution failed for task ':preBuild'.
>   failed to find Build Tools revision 19.0.0

***BUILD FAILED***

I just want to setup a simple, decent, working Android development environment on a 32 bit Ubuntu OS!

Directions/guides/hints/help please!

***btw, please don't suggest moving to a 64 bit Linux...at least not for now***

Comment: For Android Studio, on downgrade platform-tools to 23.0.1, I got two errors in the app build.gradle. Which are: failed to resolve `com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.0` and also failed to resolve `com.android.support:design:19` (on the lines `androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.0',` and `compile 'com.android.support:design:19'` in the build.gradle file respectively)

Comment: I managed to get a sample full app/build.gradle file from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21449947/how-do-i-set-the-minimum-api-level-for-projects-in-android-studio. Now error is `Error:The SDK Build Tools revision (19.1.0) is too low for project ':app'. Minimum required is 25.0.0`. Is there a way I can get gradle to stop gunning for this high api level?

Comment: In reponse to your last question, I would guess change '<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16"/>' in AndroidManifest.xml. I am not sure about that, just guessing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally came up with a rather easy way out: run Windows in a Virtual Machine!

While Google dropped support for 32 bit Linux, it still supports 32 bit Windows.

So all I did was to install 32 bit Windows on my 32 bit Linux Machine and then run Android Studio on top of that - installed all pre-requisites like Android SDK...etc. From this point onward, I simply shifted focus to looking for support/guides in Windows-Oriented guides. Easy, Cool, Simple!

Answer (score 6):

Following [this](https://www.hanshq.net/command-line-android.html) fantastic tutorial for 64 bit, I managed to get it working 100% on 32bit Ubuntu Linux, running on an old Celeron PC. I created the hellow orld app, and ran it on my Samsung A5. The entire process took about 3  to 4 hours as I had to figure some things out for 32 bit.

The version numbers are dated, but important, as the current versions do not support 64 bit.

1. sudo apt-get install gradle
2. install oracle 8

   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
       sudo apt update; sudo apt install oracle-java8-installer
       javac -version (to confirm version)
       sudo apt install oracle-java8-set-default

   (set this java version as default)

   export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-i386
   export PATH=${JAVA_HOME}/bin:$PATH
3. Install adndroid SDK

> ```
>   curl -O https://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r21.0.1-linux.tgz
>   tar zxf android-sdk_r21.0.1-linux.tgz
>   curl -O https://dl.google.com/android/repository/build-tools_r21-linux.zip
>   unzip build-tools_r21-linux.zip
>   mkdir android-sdk-linux/build-tools
>   mv android-5.0 android-sdk-linux/build-tools/21.0.1
>   curl -O https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android-16_r05.zip
>   unzip android-16_r05.zip
>   mv android-4.1.2 android-sdk-linux/platforms/android-16
>   curl -O https://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r21-linux.zip
>   unzip platform-tools_r21-linux.zip -d android-sdk-linux/
> ```

4. Write "Hello World" app folders

> ```
> cd ~
> mkdir android
> cd android
> mkdir helloworld
> cd helloworld
> ```

5. create "AndroidManifest.xml" as follows :

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
>       <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>             package="net.gavin.hello"
>               versionCode="1"
>               versionName="0.1">
>       <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16"/>
>       <application android:label="Hello">
>           <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
>               <intent-filter>
>                   <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
>                   <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
>               </intent-filter>
>           </activity>
>       </application>
>   </manifest>
> ```

6. create folders "res/layout/"

> ```
> cd ~/android/helloworld
>       mkdir res
>       cd res
>       mkdir layout
>       cd layout
> ```

7. create "activity_main.xml" as follows

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>        <LinearLayout
>           xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>           android:layout_width="match_parent"
>           android:layout_height="match_parent"
>           android:gravity="center"
>           android:orientation="vertical">
>           <TextView
>               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>               android:id="@+id/my_text"/>         </LinearLayout>
> ```

8. java/net/gavin/hello/

> ```
> cd ~ 
> mkdir java
> cd java
> mkdir net
> cd net
> mkdir gavin
> cd gavin
> mkdir hello
> ```

9.create " MainActivity.java" as follows

```
package net.gavin.hello;
        import android.app.Activity;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.widget.TextView;
        public class MainActivity extends Activity
        {
            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
            {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                TextView text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.my_text);
                text.setText("Hello, world!");
            }
        }
```

10. Create build enviroment

    cd ~
        SDK="${HOME}/android-sdk-linux"
        BUILD_TOOLS="${SDK}/build-tools/21.0.1"
        PLATFORM="${SDK}/platforms/android-16"
        mkdir -p build/gen build/obj build/apk
11. Create R.java (build/gen/net/gavin/hello/R.java)

"${BUILD_TOOLS}/aapt" package -f -m -J build/gen/ -S res -M AndroidManifest.xml -I "${PLATFORM}/android.jar"

12. Compile it

    javac -source 1.7 -target 1.7 -bootclasspath "${JAVA_HOME}/jre/lib/rt.jar" \
        -classpath "${PLATFORM}/android.jar" -d build/obj \
        build/gen/net/gavin/hello/R.java java/net/gavin/hello/MainActivity.java
13. Convert to Dalvik code

    "${BUILD_TOOLS}/dx" --dex --output=build/apk/classes.dex build/obj/
14. Package contents together

    "${BUILD_TOOLS}/aapt" package -f -M AndroidManifest.xml -S res/ \
            -I "${PLATFORM}/android.jar" \
            -F build/Hello.unsigned.apk build/apk/
15. Align to 4 byte boundry
    `"${BUILD_TOOLS}/zipalign" -f 4 build/Hello.unsigned.apk build/Hello.aligned.apk`
16. Create key store and key
    `keytool -genkeypair -keystore keystore.jks -alias androidkey \
        -validity 10000 -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 \
        -storepass android -keypass android`
17. Install ket signer (apksigner)
    `sudo apt-get install apksigner`
18. Sign app with key
    `"apksigner" sign --ks keystore.jks \
        --ks-key-alias androidkey --ks-pass pass:android \
        --key-pass pass:android --out build/Hello.apk \
        build/Hello.aligned.apk`
19. Install to device
    `"${SDK}/platform-tools/adb" install -r build/Hello.apk`
20. Run on device 
    `"${SDK}/platform-tools/adb" shell am start -n net.gavin.hello/.MainActivity`
21. Celebrate *famously*, cos that was hectic.

NB : 19 and 20 assume you have set your phone to developer mode, and it's connected to your PC via USB. In this case I simply ftp'd it to my phone, and installed from there. No problems.

Comment: Whao! That's a ton!!

Comment: It appears that way, but if you follow the process step by step, and deal with any (hopefully minor) issues as you stumble accross them, to should not take long at all.

Comment: PS, formatting this to at least show all the code seemed to me to be more of a challenge than getting the code to compile....

Comment: Just a side-note: step 17 might turn into a whole new task if your repositories don't provide the `apksigner` tool. For Ubuntu it is available only in Artful and Bionic (latest LTS, not yet released). I actually didn't have a problem downloading the Artful DEB package on my Ubuntu 16.04 and installing it (you will first need to install `fastjar` and then `jarwrapper` otherwise dependencies will not be met).

Comment: Getting `error type 3 Activity class {net.gavin.hello/net.gavin.hello.MainActivity} does not exist.` on step 20. Will have to dig deeper.

Comment: As I stated I used ftp to install to my phone, so alas did not test step 19 and 20. Those steps are straight out the original article, so if you figure out the problem please let me know. You are correct about step 17. I was very (happily) suprised when it just ran with no issues for me - Ubuntu 17.10 artful.

Comment: I just tested adb by connecting a serial cable, and even step 20 ran 100%.

Comment: ... and then set up adb to run over wifi, and also working 100%.

Comment: @"Gavin Simpson" awesome! i wish i could give much more than one rate to you. thanks a lot