# Android: confused about compileSdkVersion + targetSdkVersion 23

Tags: java, android, sdk

I want an app to be available in the play store for android M users to download, but the permissions model isn't yet complete for the app. If I set the compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion to 22 instead of 23 - will the android M users see the app and be able to dl it (granting all permissions at runtime)?

```
compileSdkVersion 22

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 22
}
```

Comment: Understand the diff here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26694108/what-is-the-difference-between-compilesdkversion-and-targetsdkversion

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> If I set the compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion to 22 instead of
>   23 - will the android M users see the app and be able to dl it
>   (granting all permissions at runtime)?

Yes, the app will be available to M users and every permission is granted at install time.

A small note, if you use the support libraries v23 you need to set the `compileSdkVersion` to 23 otherwise you get this error:

> This support library should not use a different version (23) than the
>   compileSdkVersion (22)

Comment: thanks - so if I understand correctly, this has no effect on visibility in the Play Store? The end-user sees the app no matter what I set in compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion?

Comment: @Jon: "The end-user sees the app no matter what I set in compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion?" -- yes. `compileSdkVersion` affects you as a developer. `targetSdkVersion` affects the runtime behavior of the app. `minSdkVersion` blocks out older devices.