# cause:failed to find target with hash string 'android-14 (Don't have API 14 in SDK manager)

Tags: java, android, android-sdk-manager

I've got an error saying "cause:failed to find target with hash string 'android-14'.

I've solved the similar problem before and resolved it by installing the recommended API level from SDK manager.

[image]

However, my SDK manager doesn't have API version 14.

[image]

1. Is there any chance I can install API 14 which doesn't exist in my SDK manager?
2. Is there any way to solve the issue without having to install the API ,every time I get this type of error?

I would appreciate your input!

Comment: Why would you *compile* with API 14 anyway? [At least read this.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26694108/what-is-the-difference-between-compilesdkversion-and-targetsdkversion)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the Standalone SDK Manager and enable 'Obsolete' at the bottom.

Comment: Same issue means ? Can't you see the SDK in the Standalone SDK Manager after you enabled obsolete sdk's  ?

Comment: sorry It works!! 
I enabled "obsolete" and closed the standalone SDK manager window to see if 14 is in the SDK(default setting) but it wasn't. but I can see 14 in standalone SDK manager which I could download 14 from there directly! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need API 14? All devices running on API 14 now have Api 15. Please check: 
http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html
There is no devices with API 14.