# Fabric.io error start Android 2.3.3 (api 10)

Tags: android, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

I have the following error:

```
12-03 12:20:08.270  28282-28312/com.topantidevelopers.goloud E/Fabric﹕ Unknown error while loading Crashlytics settings. Crashes will be cached until settings can be retrieved.
        java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.android.okhttp.internal.http.Transport.writeRequestHeaders(com.android.okhttp.Request)' on a null object reference
                at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:599)
                at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:379)
                at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:323)
                at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getHeaderField(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:152)
                at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getHeaderField(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:190)
                at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getHeaderField(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:25)
                at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.network.HttpRequest.header(HttpRequest.java:1875)
                at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.settings.DefaultSettingsSpiCall.invoke(DefaultSettingsSpiCall.java:93)
                at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.settings.DefaultSettingsController.loadSettingsData(DefaultSettingsController.java:80)
                at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.settings.DefaultSettingsController.loadSettingsData(DefaultSettingsController.java:64)
```

Also appeared this message at the time of import of libraries:

`io-fabric-sdk-android_fabric] Using 1.7 requires compiling with Android 4.4 (KitKat); Currently using API 10`

Maybe it's version.

Can someone help me?

Comment: This actually looks like it's a bug in `OkHttp` and not in Fabric. What version of OkHttpClient are you using?

Comment: How do I View a version ? @EpicPandaForce

Comment: @EpicPandaForce This stack trace is from API >= 21 device. NPE is better described and **Android uses OkHttp as HTTP stack implementation. It's part of Android, not imported as a library.** (Package name starts with `com.android.okhttp`.)

Comment: @CleidimarViana Can you update your question (DO NOT put it in comments) with your `build.gradle` files? **Did you configure Crashlytics properly?** Have you tried any other HTTP requests using `HttpUrlConnection` from this device? Do you have Internet connection on this device? What device are you using? Please read carefully and answer all of the above.

Comment: @EugenPechanec Came another message: Yo-fabric-sdk-android fabric] Using 1.7 requires compiling with Android 4.4 (KitKat); Currently using API 10 - Maybe it's version.

Comment: @CleidimarViana That's nice, I have a hunch, however can you do what I asked in my previous comment so I can be sure? (Update your answer with `build.gradle` files.)

Comment: @EugenPechanec  I'm not using Android Studio, but Eclipse.
I created a file called kits.properties with the following content:
`com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.5`
Only that.

Comment: @CleidimarViana **a)** Read this http://stackoverflow.com/a/26694276/2444099. I think you're compiling against several years old API 10. Basically you'll want to compile against latest Android (API 23) and keep minSdk="10" to support old devices. Read how that works. **b)** Use this plugin to configure Crashyltics if you're not doing that already. https://docs.fabric.io/android/fabric/eclipse.html