# Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.1

Tags: android

I recently changed my mindSdkVersion to 17 and targetSdkVersion to 21, and got lots of errors. I fixed some of them, but I can't fix this one:

```
Error:(28, 13) Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.1
```

I'm using Android Studio on Mac and I have Android Support repositories.

My build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.swit.sedamaker"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 2
        versionName "1.01"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.1'

    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Replace with:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
```

Comment: @AmirAmini, Sure u want to keep `targetSdkVersion 21`  at 21, try to upgrade to 23

Comment: thanks it worked, got other errors but I fixed them. but now I can't install it on the Emulator. it says there is another version of my app installed but it's the first time I'm running my app on this emulator.

Comment: @AmirAmini, Consider accepting answer if helped. Clean your project.

Comment: found out the emulator's storage was full. thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

The error occur because  21.0.1 for support libraries doesn't exist.

```
dependencies{

//it requires compileSdkVersion 21
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.2'
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0'

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're better to match the API version for `compileSdkVersion`, `buildToolsVersion`, `targetSdkVersion`. Try to use the latest SDK

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        ...
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 24
        ...
    }
    ...
}

dependencies {

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
    ...
}
```

Of course you can set targetSdkVersion to 21 if you want. targetSdkVersion is used to inform the system that you have test the app against the target version like the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html) said.

> android:targetSdkVersion
>
> An integer designating the API Level that the
>   application targets. If not set, the default value equals that given
>   to minSdkVersion. This attribute informs the system that you have
>   tested against the target version and the system should not enable any
>   compatibility behaviors to maintain your app's forward-compatibility
>   with the target version. The application is still able to run on older
>   versions (down to minSdkVersion).

Read more at [What is the difference between compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26694108/what-is-the-difference-between-compilesdkversion-and-targetsdkversion) for`compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion`.