# Version integration in `Android`

Tags: android

I'm trying to execute my application in emulator having `minSdkVersion` 22, `compileSdkVersion` 25 and `targetSdkVersion` 25 but the emulator doesn't show my application. However, when I try to do the same with emulator having `targetSdkVersion` 24 my application executes successfully. I wanted to know why is this happening and how to solve this problem of version integration?

Comment: Have you created emulator for API version `25`?

Comment: https://medium.com/google-developers/picking-your-compilesdkversion-minsdkversion-targetsdkversion-a098a0341ebd#.af1q7kd3r

Answer (score 0):

check this question:
[What is the difference between compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26694108/what-is-the-difference-between-compilesdkversion-and-targetsdkversion)

an example of this link says :
For example, setting this value to "11" or higher allows the system to apply a new default theme (Holo) to your app when running on Android 3.0 or higher...

target sdk version has different features for different versions