# Android Emulator errors?

Tags: android, android-studio, emulation

I have not been able to start my Android Application on Android Studio 2.2. So I went and look for the Logcat but here's the thing, I do not know where to look for or filter which part as there are just too many things. I really don't think it's my Application but the system that has problems.

I am currently using API 19 as the target sdkversion.

AndroidManifest.xml:`

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".CreateAccActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_create_acc"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light" />
    <activity
        android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_login"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light" />
    <activity
        android:name=".LandingActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_landing"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light" />
    <activity
        android:name=".SearchActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_search"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light" />
    <activity
        android:name=".RentEndActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_rent_end"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light" />
    <activity
        android:name=".RentStartActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_rent_start"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light" />
    <activity
        android:name=".SearchResultsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_search_results"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"></activity>
</application>
```

`

My compilesdkversion is 25,
   minimumsdkversion is 16,
   targetsdkversion is 19 (The one I am using)

Comment: Share your logcat

Answer (score 1):

That kind of problems accurs due to target, compile, and mininum sdk level, as we set in `build.gradle` file. Like as you set targetsdkversion is 19 and if you are trying to run your app on more then 19 sdk level emulator, in that case your application will not be run. so try to set your  `targetsdkversion as 24`.  as you set  `compilesdkversion is 25` is good. May be your problem will be solve.

Comment: So if I am using an API 19 to build my app, can my Targetsdkversion and Compilesdkversion be higher??

Comment: you can set your  API 19 in your build.gradle file, in that case you only able to run your app on from minimumsdk level to api level 19  device OS.

Comment: If you want to much more information about compile and targeted sdk level so please refer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26694108/what-is-the-difference-between-compilesdkversion-and-targetsdkversion

Answer (score 0):

Try to run the emulator from command line which will show errors if any while emulator startup and there by u can isolate your issue.

```
> cd <sdkpath>/emulator
> emulator @youravdname
```