# Run-time exception (java.lang.NoSuchMethodError) was fired when using the method checkSelfPermission

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, runtimeexception, runtime-permissions

Following exception was fired when using the method `checkSelfPermission`. The targetSDKVersion is 21 for the application.

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: app.Rvamd.RecoverAllMyDeletedFile, PID:
>   3700 java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method
>   checkSelfPermission(Landroid/content/Context;Ljava/lang/String;)I in
>   class Landroid/support/v4/content/ContextCompat; or its super classes
>   (declaration of 'android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat' appears in
>   /data/app/app.Rvamd.RecoverAllMyDeletedFile-1/base.apk)

Does anybody have idea on this? The method was invoked properly for another application in same emulator device. 
Apart from this, **can I know how support library methods are selected by phone/emulator** (method is invoked properly for some application while others aren't) ?

The code is as below

```
     if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                        Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS},
                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_CONTACTS);
                return;


        }
```

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Problem solved??..that's cool

Comment: @ankitpatidar No no.. I am not that much lucky :(. I meant, the code is updated.

Answer (score 1):

You might need to upgrade `compileSdkVersion` to 23. This is because runtime permission feature is added since API 23.

Comment: To be clear, Does the phone select support library version by looking at the `compileSdkVersion` ?  I noticed `compileSdkVersion` is not considered after the compilation.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure on that. There are various options on the differences among `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26694108/what-is-the-difference-between-compilesdkversion-and-targetsdkversion It still sound very confusing to me. My rule of thumb is that, I always set `compileSdkVersion` equals to `targetSdkVersion`, although they are allowed to be different.