# Instant App Not Compiling

Tags: android, android-instant-apps

When I am trying to compile with following configuration in base feature,

compileSdkVersion 25
targetSdkVersion 25

I get the below error message

"Feature modules require compileSdkVersion set to 26 or higher. compileSdkVersion is set to 25"

Is there a relation between compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion of instant app and installable app ? Please help.

Comment: Check this... might help you 
https://stackoverflow.com/q/26694108/4511245

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a compileSdkVersion of 26. You should always use the highest possible value for compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion. This does not affect backward compatibility. Moreover, Google requires current values for uploading to Google Play.

Comment: I set the targetSdkVersion to 25 and compileSdkVersion to 26. I was able to compile but when I try to upload in play store, it required a targetSdkversion of 26.

Comment: Jonas, thanks for your answer. I have one more question if you can help me with.

Comment: I uploaded my instant app on internal test track. Will internal test users see the TRY NOW button on play store ?