# java.lang.IllegalStateException during androidx.work.impl.background.systemjob.SystemJobScheduler.scheduleInternal

Tags: android, android-workmanager

We are using the following WorkManager

```
def work_version = "1.0.0-alpha02"
implementation "android.arch.work:work-runtime:$work_version" // use -ktx for Kotlin
// optional - Firebase JobDispatcher support
implementation "android.arch.work:work-firebase:$work_version"
```

We not upgraded from `1.0.0-alpha02`, as we want to maintain our `targetSdkVersion 27`.

In production, we notice the following crash report.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
  at android.os.Parcel.readException (Parcel.java:1701)
  at android.os.Parcel.readException (Parcel.java:1646)
  at android.app.job.IJobScheduler$Stub$Proxy.schedule (IJobScheduler.java:158)
  at android.app.JobSchedulerImpl.schedule (JobSchedulerImpl.java:42)
  at androidx.work.impl.background.systemjob.SystemJobScheduler.scheduleInternal (SystemJobScheduler.java:85)
  at androidx.work.impl.background.systemjob.SystemJobScheduler.schedule (SystemJobScheduler.java:64)
  at androidx.work.impl.Schedulers.scheduleInternal (Schedulers.java:98)
  at androidx.work.impl.Schedulers.schedule (Schedulers.java:69)
  at androidx.work.impl.WorkManagerImpl.rescheduleEligibleWork (WorkManagerImpl.java:398)
  at androidx.work.impl.utils.ForceStopRunnable.run (ForceStopRunnable.java:69)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:762)
```

Please advice how we can get rid of these crashed. Thanks.

Comment: You absolutely don't need to change your `targetSdkVersion` to upgrade past `1.0.0-alpha02` (just your `compileSdkVersion`).

Comment: Argh... I think I had mixed up compileSdkVersion with  targetSdkVersion. We never use compileSdkVersion before this. I'm going to give it a try, although I still can hardly understand the difference among 2 after reading https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26694108/what-is-the-difference-between-compilesdkversion-and-targetsdkversion Thanks.

Comment: There's a [whole blog post](https://medium.com/google-developers/picking-your-compilesdkversion-minsdkversion-targetsdkversion-a098a0341ebd) on how completely differently they affect your app.

Comment: Thank you. I will take a look too.

Comment: @ianhanniballake One question. If I were to change `compileSdkVersion` to 28, am I forced to use `28.0.0 Alpha 1` support library (appcompat, design, gridlayout, ...) as well? As, gradle gives me such warning? Can I just stay with 27.1.1? As I do not feel comfortable with alpha version of lib.

Comment: You can ignore the warning if you want. FWIW, every Google app ships with the alpha version of the Support Library, so it is well tested in production.