# Should targetSdKVersion be set in the project build.gradle file or the app/build.gradle file

Tags: android, gradle

I am trying to update an existing app to target SDK 33. The project currently has the following in the project `build.gradle` file.

```
ext {
compileSdkVersion = 30
targetSdkVersion = 30
// more stuff
}
```

The module `app/build.gradle` file has this

```
android {
    // more stuff    
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

    defaultConfig {
        // more stuff
        targetSdkVersion 30

    }
```

I am going to change the `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` values in the project `build.gradle` file to 33. I see where the module `app/build.gradle` file references the `compileSdkVersion` value in the project `build.gradle` file. Is there a way to do the same with the `targetSdkVersion` value? Or do I need to manually set it to 33? What happens if I leave the `targetSdkVersion` value at 30 in the module `app/build.gradle` file?

Answer (score 1):

To set `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` to 33:

```
ext {
    compileSdkVersion = 33
    targetSdkVersion = 33
    // more stuff
}
```

To use the references from project `build.gradle` file for `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion`:

```
android {
    // more stuff    
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

    defaultConfig {
        // more stuff
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion

    }
...
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26694276/12629252) the answer about the difference between `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion`, I recommend you to have both of these values the same

Comment: Thanks! Do you know which value would be used if the `targetSdkVersion` is different in the project `build.gradle` and the module `app/build.gradle` files?

Comment: @ponder275 will be used the value from app/build.gradle, because project build.gradle doesn't have "android {...}" block but can have "ext {...}" block which is used as a constants storage like in your case