# Supertypes of the following classes cannot be resolved: android app can't run

Tags: android, kotlin, android-studio

When I tried to run my application, below errors are showing:

```
> Task :app:compileDebugKotlin FAILED
e: Supertypes of the following classes cannot be resolved. Please make sure you have the required dependencies in the classpath:
    class android.view.animation.LinearInterpolator, unresolved supertypes: android.graphics.animation.NativeInterpolator
    class android.view.animation.AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator, unresolved supertypes: android.graphics.animation.NativeInterpolator
Adding -Xextended-compiler-checks argument might provide additional information.
```

**build.gradle:app**

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id 'com.google.dagger.hilt.android'
    id "jacoco"
}
jacoco {
    toolVersion("0.8.11")
}
apply from: "$project.rootDir/jacoco.gradle"

//this for getting version name from ChangeLog.md file

def getVersionName() {
    File file = file('../ChangeLog.md')
    return file.readLines().get(0)
}
//this for getting version code from ChangeLog.md file
def getVersionCode() {
    File file = file('../ChangeLog.md')
    return file.readLines().get(1)
}

def versionNameInQuotes = getVersionName()
def versionCodeNumber = getVersionCode() as Integer

android {
    namespace 'com.example.testapp'
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.testapp"
        minSdk 31
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode versionCodeNumber
        versionName "$versionNameInQuotes"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        archivesBaseName = "TestApp"
    }

    buildFeatures {
        buildConfig true
    }



    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    }

    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }

    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '11'
        // allWarningsAsErrors = true
    }

    packagingOptions {
        resources {
            excludes += ['META-INF/INDEX.LIST', 'META-INF/io.netty.versions.properties']
        }
    }
    testOptions {
        unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
        unitTests.includeAndroidResources = true
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.aar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation project(path: ':testservice')

    implementation Dependencies.core_ktx
    implementation Dependencies.appcompat
    implementation Dependencies.material
    implementation Dependencies.constraintlayout
    implementation Dependencies.livedata_ktx
    implementation Dependencies.view_model_ktx
    testImplementation Dependencies.test_junit
    androidTestImplementation Dependencies.ext_junit
    androidTestImplementation Dependencies.espresso_core

    //Hilt
    implementation(Dependencies.hilt_android)
    kapt(Dependencies.hilt_compiler)

    //Gson converter
    implementation(Dependencies.gson_retrofit_converter)

    //Mockito
    testImplementation(Dependencies.mockito_core)
    testImplementation(Dependencies.mockito_kotlin)

    androidTestImplementation(Dependencies.mockito_core)
    androidTestImplementation(Dependencies.mockito_kotlin)
    androidTestImplementation Dependencies.mockito_android

    //core testing
    testImplementation Dependencies.core_testing

    // Hilt testing dependency
    androidTestImplementation Dependencies.hilt_android_testing
    // Make Hilt generate code in the androidTest folder
    kaptAndroidTest Dependencies.hilt_compiler

    //Gson
    implementation Dependencies.gson

    //reflection
    testImplementation Dependencies.kotlin_reflect

    //coroutine testing
    testImplementation Dependencies.coroutines_test
    //datastore
    implementation Dependencies.datastore_preferences
    implementation(Dependencies.coroutines_android)

    //for Ui testing
    androidTestImplementation(Dependencies.test_runner)
    androidTestImplementation(Dependencies.test_rules)
    androidTestImplementation(Dependencies.ui_automator)
    implementation(Dependencies.espresso_contrib)
}
```

**build.gradle(ServiceApp)**

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.library'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id 'com.google.dagger.hilt.android'
    id 'jacoco'
}

jacoco {
    toolVersion("0.8.11")
}
apply from:"$project.rootDir/jacoco.gradle"

android {
    namespace 'com.example.testservice'
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        minSdk 31
        targetSdk 32

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        consumerProguardFiles "consumer-rules.pro"
    }
    buildFeatures {
        buildConfig true
    }
   
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '11'
    }
    testOptions {
        unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
        unitTests.includeAndroidResources = true
    }
}

dependencies {
    api fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    api project(":telematicslib")
    implementation Dependencies.core_ktx
    implementation Dependencies.appcompat
    implementation Dependencies.material

    //HiveMQ
    implementation(Dependencies.mqtt_client)

    //Retrofit
    implementation(Dependencies.retrofit)
    //Gson converter
    implementation(Dependencies.gson_retrofit_converter)
    implementation(Dependencies.okHttpLoggingInterceptor)
    implementation files('libs\\extension-V1.0-java.jar')

    testApi Dependencies.test_junit
    androidTestApi Dependencies.ext_junit
    androidTestApi Dependencies.espresso_core

    //datastore
    implementation Dependencies.datastore_preferences
    implementation(Dependencies.coroutines_android)

    //Hilt
    implementation(Dependencies.hilt_android)
    kapt(Dependencies.hilt_compiler)

    //Mockito
    testApi (Dependencies.mockito_core)
    testApi (Dependencies.mockito_kotlin)
    //core testing
    testApi Dependencies.core_testing

    // Hilt testing dependency
    testApi Dependencies.hilt_android_testing
    // Make Hilt generate code in the androidTest folder
    kaptAndroidTest Dependencies.hilt_compiler

    //reflection
    testApi Dependencies.kotlin_reflect


    //coroutine testing
    testApi Dependencies.coroutines_test
}
```

I tried below steps:

1. Android Studio -> File -> Invalidate cache/restart
2. Deleted build folder from My app
3. Build ---> clean project, Build ---> Rebuild Project
4. Restarted Laptop, Android Studio
5. It is working when I am changing compile and target sdk to 33. But I need to work my app in sdk 32.

Comment: Why do you need to have `compileSdk` and `targetSdk` on 32? It is usually recommended to have these two on the highest available SDK. Ony `minSdk` should be as low as possible to support many Android versions. Check out this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26694108/what-is-the-difference-between-compilesdkversion-and-targetsdkversion

Comment: @BenjyTec : Thank you for your response. This app mainly for specific vendor. In their system only support android sdk 32 and they specially requested us to use the same that's why we are using sdk32.