# meaning of android target when building tess-two ocr

Tags: android, sdk, target, tess-two

I am following this tutorial - http://gaut.am/making-an-ocr-android-app-using-tesseract/ in order to build and use the tess-two library.

**I ran into an error when running**

> android update project --path .

**and in the tutorials, it says:**

> On Windows: “The project either has no target set or the target is
>   invalid. Please provide a –target to the ‘android.bat update’
>   command.” Solution: Run the command android update project --path
>   D:\Softwares\Studies\Android\OCR\Code_Project\tess-two-master\tess-two
>   --target android-19

I ran the command with the android-19 target, and it worked.

**My question is** - what is the meaning of the target SDK (in this case, android-19) that I put in the build command?

does it mean it will be the minimum version for it to run on or anything like that??

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Setting the target SDK ensures that you can use the features from that SDK.
It is the version your application was targeted to run on. 
It is not the minimum version for the application to run on. Here are a few reference question's that will clear your doubts.
[Difference in Target and the minSDK version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24510219/android-studio-min-skd-version-target-sdk-version-vs-compile-sdk-version)

And here is one more: [Android Min SDK Version vs. Target SDK Version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4568267/android-min-sdk-version-vs-target-sdk-version)

Comment: thanks for your answer. so lets say I built it with android-19, and in my app I have Min SDK - 15 and Target SDK - 22, will it work nicely?

Comment: Good question. I think it will not. You are building using 19 version. If u might use some feature of 22 it might not work. 15 as min sdk will be fine as that just ensures backward compatibility:-)

Comment: Still im not sure about this.

Comment: but lets say that I am not using any feature from the 22, it will be fine? just testing the library