# Setting SDK version for new project in AS

Tags: android, android-studio, ide, android-api-levels

I am having an issue that I have three API levels downloaded 20,21 and 23. Whenever I create a new project ,API 23 will automatically be selected but I want API 20 project.

[image]

If I make changes in `build.gradle` file , like

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 20 // previously 23
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.abc.xyz"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 20// previously 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
```

it starts giving me numerous errors which are obvious but I'm unable to resolve them easily

[image]

My problem is why I can't start a new fresh API 20 project, as I don't need this for API 23.

Do I need to put different APIs in different directories?or there is any other way to achieve this

Comment: And the errors you are getting are? Why do you want to use an API 20 project? You can compile with 23 but target 20 without a problem.

Comment: @LordRaydenMK as my organizations's other apps are at API 20, as you suggested that I can have different compile and target level, can you point me any explanation for this, I think this is the point where I am getting confuse..that after compiling code with 23 i'll unable to run with lower devices...

Comment: also I have updated the screenshot with errors I first getting after making changes to gradle, if I remove these style, it then points to some other places and keep going until i get confuse what to do,

Answer (score 0):

In android studio goto **FILE -> Project Structure**

and change **Compiled sdk version** and apply changes [image: chnage compile sdk]

Comment: this is what I am doing and getting errors as I mentioned, I need to know for where I can change the default api 23 to API 20

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are using v23 of the support libraries.

To use v23 of the support libraries your `compileSdk` need to be set to 23. [Source](https://plus.google.com/+ChrisBanes/posts/ekKcJwtCW9U)

You can read about the difference between `targetSdk` and `compileSdk` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24510219/android-studio-min-sdk-version-target-sdk-version-vs-compile-sdk-version) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26694108/what-is-the-difference-between-compilesdkversion-and-targetsdkversion?lq=1).

You are getting errors because you have `compileSdk` set to 20 and you are using support libraries v23.

You can either increase the `compileSdk` to 23 or use older support libraries.

I don't see a reason not to target API 23 and target API 20.