# Android Studio Gradle Wont Compile

Tags: java, android

I have been working on an Android application for several months, and didn't realize until today that it was targeting the level 25 for "Compile SDK Version." I want my app to be usable on versions of Android starting at API level 22 (Android 5.1). I went into my gradle settings and set a couple things...

compileSdkVersion 22

targetSdkVersion 22

I also changed the versions of the libraries it compiles with..

```
compile project(':snakeyaml-1.14-android')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:22.2.1'
```

I get the following error...

"Failed to resolve: com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:22.2.1"

What should I do?

Comment: android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "YOUR_APP_ID"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}

Comment: To support lower version use munadi version and keep compile to latest

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33947660/what-should-i-set-for-compilesdkversion-minsdkversion-and-targetsdkversion. Check this for clarification