# Getting NullPointerException only on few devices while using setAdapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, android-viewpager, android-adapter

I am using Vertical `ViewPager` while using `setAdapter` i'm checking whether the `verticalViewPager` and `arrayPagerAdapter` is **Null** or not but still i'm getting below Logcat exception on **Few Devices** but not in all devices.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.os.Handler android.support.v4.app.FragmentHostCallback.getHandler()' on a null object reference
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:1623)
   at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:637)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:166)
   at com.inheadline.news.view.viewpager.VerticalViewPager.setAdapter(VerticalViewPager.java:278)
   at com.inheadline.news.activity.MainActivity.setupViewPager(MainActivity.java:487)
   at com.inheadline.news.activity.MainActivity.dataAdded(MainActivity.java:557)
   at com.inheadline.news.db.operation.DataSnapshotToDb$AddToDb.onPostExecute(DataSnapshotToDb.java:163)
   at com.inheadline.news.db.operation.DataSnapshotToDb$AddToDb.onPostExecute(DataSnapshotToDb.java:138)
   at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:679)
   at android.os.AsyncTask.access$500(AsyncTask.java:180)
   at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:696)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5546)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:794)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:684)
```

Here is my code while setting view pager:

```
if (verticalViewPager != null && arrayPagerAdapter != null) {
        verticalViewPager.setAdapter(arrayPagerAdapter);
        verticalViewPager.setSwipable(true);
        verticalViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(pageChangeListener);
    }
```

In above code `MainActivity.java:487` is `verticalViewPager.setAdapter(arrayPagerAdapter);`

Comment: dude full adapter class and async class

Comment: can you also post your gradle dependencies?

Comment: @Rahul i'm not doing nothing much on Async class. For adapter im getting help from this https://github.com/takaaki7/ArrayPagerAdapter and im using ArrayFragmentPagerAdapter from this link

Comment: @RohitArya : Im just using compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1' and for VerticalViewPager its custom class.

Comment: show your gradle imports ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is already a reported bug([report1](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=216157), [report2](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=218912), [report3](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=183920), [report4](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=208911)).

I was myself facing the problem and I moved from `'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'` to compile `'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.0'` and that solved the problem for me. So try to rollback the support library version and see if that works for you. Remember to rollback all the android support lib version to `23.1.0`.

Comment: I am using v7:24.1.1 and i think it is not necessary to put v4. You mean should i use v7:23.1.0 ?

Comment: I am using targetSdkVersion 24 if i use v7:23.1.0 i have to use targetSdkVersion 23. It will make problem or not?

Comment: you can read about this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26694108/what-is-the-difference-between-compilesdkversion-and-targetsdkversion) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24510219/what-is-the-difference-between-min-sdk-version-target-sdk-version-vs-compile-sd). It will clear things out. :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If i do not get this issue again i'll accept this answer.