# (Target sdk vs Maxsdkversion) How this will differ my application process?

Tags: android, sdk, manifest, android-version

```
 <uses-sdk
    android:targetSdkVersion="21"
    android:minSdkVersion="11" />
```

In my application,i am not providing any maximumsdkversion and i tested it in Lollipop,

> Whether all the functionality can work in Marshmallow also?

or

> i need to provide maximumsdkversion 23 in manifest?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Please look at : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24510219/what-is-the-difference-between-min-sdk-version-target-sdk-version-vs-compile-sd

Comment: max sdk version only limits app not to be shown in google play for devices with higher SDK

Comment: @VladMatvienko if i install the app in device directly,without upload in google market, whether it can work in marshmallow?

Comment: yes, it will work. It is ONLY for play store

Answer (score 0):

TargetSdkVersion implies the sdk version for which you are developing. The devices having a lower sdk version of Android OS would be able to use it. In case you want to use features such as dynamic permission you will have to target the sdk 23 or above.

Minimum sdk version on the other hand is the minimum sdk version of android you want to support. Devices having a lower sdk version won't be able to install your app. It will not be shown in play store for such devices.