# I want to keep the minSdkVersion 14 and the targetSdkVersion 19 and the compiledSdkVersion 23. Is it is technically OK?

Tags: android

I want to keep the `min Sdk Version` 14 and the `target Sdk Version 19` and the `compiled Sdk Version 23`. Is it is technically OK or not?
 if it is OK then will my App run properly on all Android devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is technically OK, & if you are not using any dangerous permission then it will work on all android devices above API 14. If you are using any permission related task, then you will have to check the permission every time before using, otherwise your app might crash over some devices.
Read for more details:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html

https://medium.com/google-developers/picking-your-compilesdkversion-minsdkversion-targetsdkversion-a098a0341ebd

Answer (score 0):

It's technically OK. Have a look at these very well described answers in other posts: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/27629181/4315095; https://stackoverflow.com/a/26694276/4315095