# Dealing with Android SDK versions and Targeting

Tags: android, google-play, publish

So we are working with Xamarin and it seems that after we upgraded our Android project it seemed to change the Target SDK of our app from 21 to 25.  We never noticed this and uploaded an .apk into Alpha Testing.

I later noticed this issue, tried to revert to v21 target and now Google is telling me it cannot because of a breaking permission change in v23 (Marshmallow).

I tried disabling the alpha testing and deleting the v25 target, but that did not work.

I did notice that I could at least downgrade to v23 Marshmallow and carry on with my app release.

BUT:  According to usage stats I've looked into I'm cutting off support for appx 15 - 25% of devices (take your pick) by only supporting Marshmallow+...

I've done some research around the issue and haven't found a way to solve it yet.  I also emailed Google Support in hopes they can help.

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Thanks!!!

Comment: New permission flow was implemented on Android 23, so if your code is using the new permissions, you may want to target latest version, and set the minimum sdk to 21 or lower. It will require some code adjustments to resolve issues most likely in your case permissions issues.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: Understand the difference between minimum/target/compile SDK. Start here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47269079/2444099 Also, by the end of year 2018, you'll have to work with recent devices in mind: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/12/improving-app-security-and-performance.html

Comment: @MoGa OK, that was exactly what I needed thank you.  Believe it or not Google Play support told me "too bad that's the way it is".  Thanks!  Really appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

@MoGa suggestion was the correct one.  Target v23 and set Minimum SDK to 21.  This worked very well, and allows me to continue to target all the devices we need to.