# How do I build a Godot project for Android using SDK version 30?

Tags: android, google-play, godot

I'm trying to build a Godot project to upload to Google play, it builds correctly and works fine but it builds with Android SDK version 29 instead of 30, which isn't supported on Google Play.

I've tried following the Godot and Google play docs for exporting a Godot project for Android but neither of them mentions the SDK version.
I've tried uninstalling the SDK versions (through Android Studio) and only installing version 30, but Godot just goes and installs version 29 during the build.

[The message it gave while downloading version 29](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rr0aS.png)

I've looked through all of the editor settings and export settings in Godot but I've yet to see anything to do with the SDK version, I've search about it on the internet but still yet to find anything related or find any hints as to the cause of this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be a build.gradle file somewhere in the exported android project (I haven't done a Godot export for android before). It will have a targetSdkVersion, compileSdkVersion, and minSdkVersion in it. If you want to deploy for API 30, then you should set target and compile SdkVersion to 30.

Here's a thread with more info on the differences:
[What is the difference between min SDK version/target SDK version vs. compile SDK version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24510219/what-is-the-difference-between-min-sdk-version-target-sdk-version-vs-compile-sd)

Comment: Thanks, you're a lifesaver!
Just to note though, I found those variables in config.gradle instead of build.gradle and you can't use API 29 as of August this year: 
https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/target-sdk.html

Comment: Oh, new apps - my bad. Glad you were able to resolve it!

I have an app that's older, they are still allowing me to push updates targeting 29 until November. Just a little further down in that link you posted.