# For Google Play, can I have my game require less than Android 12 to download?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play, google-play-console, google-play-developer-api

I have built a game for Android that I am pretty exited about and proud of. I have released it to the app store but in order to download the game it needs to have Android 12 or above. I know very few people who currently have that new of an Android phone which heavily limits my audience. Is there a way that I can change the game to where it requires less than Android 12? Also the game is built in Unity if that changes anything.

Thank you,
Tyrone McClanahan

Link to game:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.TyMcClanahan.BoomerangBilly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update the `minSdkVersion` field on the AndroidManifest.xml

See https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/platforms

You can choose the value of `minSdkVersion` that matches the Android API Level  that your app is compatible with.

Make sure not to confuse `minSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion`. The latter only configures the behaviour of the app and not the eligibility of devices for your app. See [What is the difference between min SDK version/target SDK version vs. compile SDK version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24510219/what-is-the-difference-between-min-sdk-version-target-sdk-version-vs-compile-sd) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the **Minimum API Level** directly in the Unity Player Settings.
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PlayerSettingsAndroid.html

With Unity 2021 you can decrease it down to **Android 5.1**, see https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/system-requirements.html