# How can I fix this version of the rendering library is more recent than your version of ADT plug-in in eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I was updated my android SDK tools to 24.1.2 and I updated to Android API 22 (that is, 5.1) and I restarted my eclipse and created new android project with target API of 22 then when I was opened my XML file it was not showing any preview. It was showing an error:

> **This version of the rendering library is more recent than your version of ADT plug-in. Please update ADT plug-in**.

Comment: Post a picture of your SDK Manager, showing what is checked and what isn't.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Go to **Help** >> **Install new software** and add install https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/ then select **Developer Tools** and click on **next** to begin install

or

Change the API version in XML.

Comment: How do you "change the API version" in XML? Do you mean the AndroidManifest?

Answer (score 28):

**Using Gradle**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/20167880/2265926

**In XML**

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
```

**In IDE**

Just try changing android version while rendering layout.

**In Eclipse :**

[image]

**In Android Studio :**

[image]

Comment: Works... but is not an ultimate solution.