# Rendering library is more recent than the latest available ADT plug-in

Tags: android, adt, eclipse-adt

I am using ADT 23.0.6 which is the latest plug-in available according to this page [Installing the ADT plug-in](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html)

But I still get this error message in Eclipse:

`This version of the rendering library is more recent than your version of ADT plug-in. Please update ADT plug-in`

How is this possible?

Comment: make a android version change in your layout. Check this--> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30558180/this-version-of-the-rendering-library-is-more-recent-than-your-version-of-adt-pl    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29124548/how-can-i-fix-this-version-of-the-rendering-library-is-more-recent-than-your-ver   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18852983/eclipse-reports-rendering-library-more-recent-than-adt-plug-in

Comment: In the graphical layout view, I selected 22 instead of 23, This seemed to fix the problem except for 23.

Answer (score 0):

In the Add Repository dialog that appears, enter "ADT Plugin" for the Name and the following URL for the Location:

```
https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/
```

> **Note**: The Android Developer Tools update site requires a secure connection. Make sure the update site URL you enter starts with HTTPS.

It worked with *Https*

source [Android Developer website](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html)