# Unable to launch application in Emulator

Tags: android, eclipse

I am using Eclipse for Android native development. For small Samples emulator is working, but when I imported Project and made to run, when I clicked on app icon.

It shows alert `The application Customer Assist(Process com.blo.customer_Assist) has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again.`

I googled it but didn't find solution

logcat

```
08-23 13:51:14.571: I/dalvikvm(309): Could not find method com.blo.Customer_Assist.activities.RescueActivity.getActionBar, referenced from method com.blo.Customer_Assist.activities.RescueActivity.onCreate
08-23 13:51:14.571: W/dalvikvm(309): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 5941: Lcom/blo/Customer_Assist/activities/RescueActivity;.getActionBar ()Landroid/app/ActionBar;
08-23 13:51:14.571: D/dalvikvm(309): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0006
08-23 13:51:14.571: D/dalvikvm(309): VFY: dead code 0x0009-0077 in Lcom/blo/Customer_Assist/activities/RescueActivity;.onCreate (Landroid/os/Bundle;)V
08-23 13:51:14.581: I/dalvikvm(309): Could not find method android.content.SharedPreferences.getStringSet, referenced from method com.blo.Customer_Assist.activities.BaseActivity.getPreferenceValue
08-23 13:51:14.581: W/dalvikvm(309): VFY: unable to resolve interface method 325: Landroid/content/SharedPreferences;.getStringSet (Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/util/Set;)Ljava/util/Set;
08-23 13:51:14.581: D/dalvikvm(309): VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0011
08-23 13:51:14.591: D/dalvikvm(309): VFY: dead code 0x0014-0014 in Lcom/blo/Customer_Assist/activities/BaseActivity;.getPreferenceValue (Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Object;
08-23 13:51:14.601: I/dalvikvm(309): Could not find method android.content.SharedPreferences$Editor.putStringSet, referenced from method com.blo.Customer_Assist.activities.BaseActivity.setPreferenceValue
08-23 13:51:14.601: W/dalvikvm(309): VFY: unable to resolve interface method 316: Landroid/content/SharedPreferences$Editor;.putStringSet (Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/util/Set;)Landroid/content/SharedPreferences$Editor;
08-23 13:51:14.611: D/dalvikvm(309): VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0012
08-23 13:51:14.611: I/dalvikvm(309): Could not find method android.content.SharedPreferences$Editor.apply, referenced from method com.blo.Customer_Assist.activities.BaseActivity.setPreferenceValue
08-23 13:51:14.611: W/dalvikvm(309): VFY: unable to resolve interface method 309: Landroid/content/SharedPreferences$Editor;.apply ()V
08-23 13:51:14.621: D/dalvikvm(309): VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0018
08-23 13:51:14.621: D/dalvikvm(309): VFY: dead code 0x001b-001b in Lcom/blo/Customer_Assist/activities/BaseActivity;.setPreferenceValue (Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
08-23 13:51:14.660: E/ResourceType(309): Style contains key with bad entry: 0x010102ce
08-23 13:51:14.671: D/AndroidRuntime(309): Shutting down VM
08-23 13:51:14.671: W/dalvikvm(309): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
08-23 13:51:14.691: E/AndroidRuntime(309): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-23 13:51:14.691: E/AndroidRuntime(309): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.blo.Customer_Assist.activities.RescueActivity.getActionBar
08-23 13:51:14.691: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at com.blo.Customer_Assist.activities.RescueActivity.onCreate(RescueActivity.java:449)
08-23 13:51:14.691: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
08-23 13:51:14.691: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
08-23 13:51:14.691: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
08-23 13:51:14.691: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
08-23 13:51:14.691: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
08-23 13:51:14.691: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-23 13:51:14.691: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-23 13:51:14.691: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
08-23 13:51:14.691: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-23 13:51:14.691: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-23 13:51:14.691: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
08-23 13:51:14.691: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
08-23 13:51:14.691: E/AndroidRuntime(309):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Post your full LogCat

Comment: @Frank N. Stein Please check logCat

Comment: are you running app on device lower than api 11 i.e on android version gingerbread

Comment: If yes then inside onCreate of Activity instead of getActionBar use getSupportActionBar and import support library v7 or follow as described in http://android-developers.blogspot.co.il/2013/08/actionbarcompat-and-io-2013-app-source.html

Comment: @Shadow Droid android:minSdkVersion="8"targetSdkVersion="19"

Comment: @berry that is what you have mention in manifest file...but I was asking version of device/emulator on which you are testing/running the app

Comment: @Shadow Droid its Android 2.3.3 and API level 10

Comment: that is why you are getting error....so solution is use getSupportActionBar method as mention in previous comments

Comment: @berry **False**. You said: `android:minSdkVersion="8"targetSdkVersion="19"`, therefore your minimum is Android **2.2** (Froyo), API Level **8**, and you are compiling with KitKat (API Level **19**)

Comment: @FrankN.Stein  bcoz of that he was getting runtime error and not compile time error....

Comment: @FrankN.Stein i created emulator of Android 4.4.2,platform 4.4.2 ,API level 19,CPU/ABI -ARM(armeabi-v7a).but i get alert Unfortunately Customer_Assist has stopped.

Comment: This is **higher** (**19**) than the **minimum** required API Level (**8**). I said `lower or equal`.

Comment: @Frank N. Stein as guided i changed emulator that have Android 2.2,API level 8 but its give same alert of it cant open App. i have updated logcat please check

Comment: Add the `support library`. Then change `getActionBar()` to `getSupportActionBar()`, as suggested by @noob

Comment: @Frank N. Stein i have added support libraries like android-suport-v7-appcompat.jar and android-support-v4.jar  and when changed getactionbar to getsupportactionbar()  it shows error saying change to getactionbar().pleaase check i have added image of files in folder.

Answer (score 0):

There's an indication in your LogCat already

```
Could not find method     com.blo.Customer_Assist.activities.RescueActivity.getActionBar, referenced from      method com.blo.Customer_Assist.activities.RescueActivity.onCreate
```

The emulator is crashing your app and thus you can't see it getting launched.
It couldn't find the `getActionBar()` method in the mentioned `Activity` class. Although it does sound strange, since all Activities in Android have this method. Are you sure you have extended an `Activity` class and used parenthesis after that? Can you post the code also, so that I can confirm?

PS: Also mention which version of Android OS are you trying in the emulator and what's the Minimum and Target API level?

**Update:**
ActionBars were implemented in HoneyComb (API level 11). So either change the minSdkVersion to 11 or use a support library to get the functionality and use getSupportActionBar() instead. More details are here - [ActionBar](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html)

Comment: its Android 2.3.3 and API level 10.In Activity Class it has getactionBar()

Comment: @berry **False**. You said: `android:minSdkVersion="8"targetSdkVersion="19"`, therefore your minimum is Android **2.2** (Froyo), API Level **8**, and you are compiling with KitKat (API Level **19**)

Comment: @Frank N. Stein should i change API level to 8 in run configration or what should i do to make emulator work.please help i dont know much about this.

Comment: @berry You need to change it in the build.gradle file in the app folder. Here's how to do it - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19465049/changing-api-level-android-studio   
    
  Instead of changing it in the emulator, create a new Emulator, that'll be faster.

Comment: @berry Just create an emulator which has a **lower or equal** API Level than the minimum required by your app.

Comment: @noob i created emulator of Android 4.4.2,platform 4.4.2 ,API level 19,CPU/ABI -ARM(armeabi-v7a).but i get alert Unfortunately Customer_Assist has stopped.

Comment: @berry Have you changed it in the build.gradle file? If yes, what exception are you getting? Is it same as before?

Comment: @noob i am using Eclipse for Android Native Development,so in this i dont have build.gradle file,so i created new Avd and run the emulator.

Comment: @berry So the answer is even simpler, use Android Studio. It's officially recommended. If you choose to use Eclipse however, you can use AndroidManifest.xml for the same setting.

Comment: @noob App is already written using eclipse i am just changing UI in that App.so Can i use the same App in Android studio,is there a Way?and in AndroidManifest.xml in eclipse setting could be done only in minsdkversion=8 and targetSDKVersion=19,as guided i changed emulator that have Android 2.2,API level 8  but its give same alert i have updated logcat please check