# Minimum SKD of dependecy is higher than project minimum SDK

Tags: android

Hello I'm importing `compile 'me.grantland:autofittextview:0.2.+'`this project is min sdk 14 and my min sdk is 9. When i compile the project error message pops out:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 9 cannot be smaller than version 14 declared in library [me.grantland:autofittextview:0.2.1] E:\Android\Projects\Colorido\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\me.grantland\autofittextview\0.2.1\AndroidManifest.xml
    Suggestion: use tools:overrideLibrary="me.grantland.widget" to force usage
```

So i added
`<uses-sdk tools:overrideLibrary="me.grantland.widget"/>` and also         `xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"`

but no change. Is there a way to change minimum sdk of imported project? Thanks.

Comment: https://github.com/grantland/android-autofittextview/blob/master/build.gradle needs minSdkVersion = 14

Answer (score 1):

Remove the override, that's a bad idea.

Your IDE should have a GUI option somewhere to change it to > 14.

Here's a previously asked question on how to change it.
[Changing API level Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19465049/changing-api-level-android-studio)

Answer (score 0):

You should change your project to library's `minimumSKD` value (in your case 14). This is because the library does not support less than `API 14` thus you can not use it according to the requirements needed... For more info click [HERE](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html).

**Therefore**, you can look for an alternative library **or** download the same library and import it to your project then change the `minimumSKD` value to 9.