# Android App not running virtually

Tags: android

I've just started Android App Developing. I've made an app which shows Hello World (Just to test). I pressed Run App button but then it showed

"minSdk(API 23,N preview)!=deviceSdk(API 19)"

under the interface.

I tried creating another emulator, but still, it shows the same message.

What should I do?

**Please see the ScreenShot

**I'm using Linux Mint 14.04.

[Screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x832s.png)

Comment: Share your manifest. The problem is your android:minSdkVersion, it must be 19 if you want your app run on sdk version 19 devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your application defines a minimum SDK of 23 while your emulators have an SDK lower than that.

Since your just building a hello world application I don't think you need the minimum SDK to be set the minimum sdk that high.

just open your build.gradle file (from the side menu on the left open Gradle Scripts  then choose build.gradle that has "module :app " written next to it) and change the property  "minSdkVersion" and set it to 14 for example and you'll be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

The version of the Android OS on your emulator is `Kitkat` whereas your application needs to be run on atleast `Android N Preview`. Change the minimum required sdk level (`minSdk`) to 19( kitkat ) and you are good to go.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20167880/5157905) Stack Overflow answer on how to change the `minSdk`.

Answer (score 0):

You can either create a new emulator with the required API version or change the API version of your project.