# Android studio 2021, where to find templates for older API Levels?

Tags: android, android-studio, templates, android-api-levels

recently I have updated Android studio to version 2022.1.1 big mistake, because I am working on some older project which has a minimum sdk set to 14 (updating minimum sdk is not possible, since it seams pointless for something that worked before), I wanted to create a basic activity but coudn't create any activity at all (even empty activity) because all the templates require minumum API level 16 (my target API level is 30)
[image]

now I don't know what changed (I know that when Android 3 (API level 11) came, then came fragments, so I guess templates creates fragmets now, but after fragments, what would template do that API level of 14 coudn't handle) because few years ago the same activity required an api level of 9 ([Selected activity template has a minimum SDK level of 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40372664/selected-activity-template-has-a-minimum-sdk-level-of-9))

So where can I get this older templates and how to install them to my Android studio?

Now there is always an option for creating activity by hand, but why do that if in the past templates covered that (I also could downgrade android studio but I don't know to which version to even downgrade and there has to be a better way then this, I hope)

Comment: Google Play services APIs require API 16, but the min SDK version for ~every other template is still 14. Which particular template do you think has a minSdkVersion higher than 14?

Comment: It aphears every template does (if you look the picture, when I am trying to select basic template, Android Studio won't let me), even empty template I cannot create