# my app is not running in android KITKAT

Tags: android

My app is running perfectly on api level 21 but not running on api 19.My dependencies are here

```
 dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
        compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
        //compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:design:23.2.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:7.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:7.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:7.8.0'
    compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: You should attach the logcat debugger to your app under Kitkat.  There should be log message or resulting exception that will give a hint to the issue.

Comment: post full `build.gradle` .post exceptions

Comment: what is 'targetSdkVersion' of your app?

Comment: android {
        compileSdkVersion 25
        buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
        useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.example.unikadell.preempt"
            minSdkVersion 18
            targetSdkVersion 25
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
            multiDexEnabled true;
        }

Comment: sorry i cant post full build.gradle. it giving error as i am new in stackoverflow. please go through my previous comment.

Comment: My minimum sdk version is 18

Comment: No one can help you without log messages and exception stacktraces

Comment: i found that when i running using usb,it running successfully. but when sending apk by mail.then it forcefully closed

Comment: Are you sending by mail the release version? If yes check out your proguard-rules if they are enabled

Comment: solved my problem

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21667156/6508589