# Android App incompatible with all devices

Tags: android

Android Developer Console says my app is incompatible with all devices. However it is tight lipped as to why. Near as I can tell the reason is, according to an article I read, most likely from my android manifest being messed up. But I can't seem to figure out why. I have another app in the app store which is compatible with everything. So what's the issue?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application


    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="Writing Analyzer"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".ResultsActivity"/>

</application>
```

Edit: Some more info
-Minimum SDK is 15

-I am only using one external library, OpenNLP

-As part of OpenNLP I have a model in the assets folder

-I have a class that extends BaseListAdapter

[image: As shown here Nothing is supported]

**Edit: Here is the full merged manifest. Sorry didn't realize at first that would be needed.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:versionCode="3"
android:versionName="2.0"
package="textsnoop.rddigi.com.textstats"
platformBuildVersionCode="25"
platformBuildVersionName="7.1.1">

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="15"
    android:targetSdkVersion="25" />

<meta-data
    android:name="android.support.VERSION"
    android:value="25.3.0" />

<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />

<uses-permission
    android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

<permission
    android:name="textsnoop.rddigi.com.textstats.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="0x2" />

<uses-permission
    android:name="textsnoop.rddigi.com.textstats.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<application
    android:theme="@ref/0x7f0800a3"
    android:label="Writing Analyzer"
    android:icon="@ref/0x7f030000"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:roundIcon="@ref/0x7f030001">

    <activity
        android:name="textsnoop.rddigi.com.textstats.MainActivity">

        <intent-filter>

            <action
                android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category
                android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="textsnoop.rddigi.com.textstats.ResultsActivity" />

    <activity
        android:theme="@ref/0x0103000f"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="0xfb0" />

    <activity
        android:theme="@ref/0x7f080111"
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.purchase.InAppPurchaseActivity" />

    <activity
        android:theme="@ref/0x01030010"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiActivity"
        android:exported="false" />

    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false" />

    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementInstallReferrerReceiver"
        android:permission="android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES"
        android:enabled="true">

        <intent-filter>

            <action
                android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false" />

    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND"
        android:exported="true">

        <intent-filter>

            <action
                android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />

            <action
                android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <category
                android:name="textsnoop.rddigi.com.textstats" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver"
        android:exported="false" />

    <service
        android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService"
        android:exported="true">

        <intent-filter
            android:priority="-500">

            <action
                android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <provider
        android:name="com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:authorities="textsnoop.rddigi.com.textstats.firebaseinitprovider"
        android:initOrder="100" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@ref/0x7f0c0003" />
</application>
```

Comment: can you share your gradle ?? there might be a problem with the minimum api level

Comment: Minimum is 15, I doubt that is the issue that makes everything unsupported.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know exactly what caused the change, but I went through and cleaned the project with lint. I also removed a call to the apache commons io from the app. I suspect that is most likely the issue.

Answer (score 0):

A possible reason for this is that your minimum API level is high, leading to your app being incompatible with many devices. Checkout: 
[Changing API level Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19465049/changing-api-level-android-studio) if you want to change your minimum API level.

Try setting all the uses-feature"-tags to false

Try removing all permissions (I know the app won't work without them, but just for the sake of figuring out why Google Play says that the app supports 0 devices)

Comment: The minimum is SDK 15 so that isn't that high.

Comment: You're right, 15 is not high. I edited the answer...see if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your permissions and features in manifest file. Especially if you're mentioning any feature/permission that has required attribute e.g: <

> uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" android:required="true"/>

Remove the "android:required=true " part then it should work fine in Play Store.

Comment: See the thing is I don't have anything like that, see the full manifest