# How to import lower API levels in Unity 2017.1.1?

Tags: api, unity-game-engine, build

I need to build an APK that could be played on Android 4.0.4 but the lowest API level Unity gives me is level 16, which is 4.1.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7w96f.png

Is there any way to make Unity build API at level 14-15?

Comment: Export it out to see if that is possible. Note that those levels are discontinued and you have to move on.

Answer (score 0):

With Unity 2017 you can export a project to Android studio (Build Settings-> Build System: Gradle, check Export Project).

Once you are in Android Studio you have all the options available to Android and should be able to set the minSdk version lower if you want. See this previous question regarding how to do that in Android Studio:

[Changing API level Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19465049/changing-api-level-android-studio)