# android install failed invalid apk version code inconsistent android O

Tags: android

INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK

This error occurs when switching flavors & building a debug version after making a release version on my Pixel2 XL. The dialog asks to uninstall the existing application but the app is already gone on the device. It seems that there is a temp file triggering this flow again and again. Restarting Android studio / cleaning doesn't seem to help so my guess is it has something to do with Android O / my Pixel2 XL.

[image]

Any clues as to how to resolve this?

Comment: try to add screenshot or log !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have experienced the same issue before. You can simply restart android device and try again. It will work.

Comment: This actually did the trick for me, I did increase the version number so that was not the issue in this case. What exactly caused this is still unclear to me.

Answer (score 3):

You can goto  AndroidStudio Setting ，and Search "Instant Run" , and close it.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot install older version over newer version (i.e. 5 over 7), only newer over older. So, you either need to increase your version code or uninstall the app before installing (what Android Studio suggests).

Answer (score 0):

You may not have that android version of your Pixel 2 in your Android Studio.

According to the screenshot, you have to add that android version to your Android Studio.

See this link: [Changing API level Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19465049/changing-api-level-android-studio)

Comment: Can you provide a solution for OP?

Comment: if you don't have the corresponding API Level already: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19465049/changing-api-level-android-studio   If you only have Problem with the Version Name or Version code, then probably: https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning.html#minsdkversion

Answer (score 0):

you can try to use `adb install xxx.apk`

if not working , try `adb uninstall your-package-name`