# How to change minimum target SDK API in Android Studio after creating new project?

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk, android-sdk-tools

I created a new project in android studio and choosed target minimum SDK then after creating new project how can i change minimum target SDK in android studio?

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/20167880/3983054

Comment: Please search for similar answered questions before asking your own

Answer (score 1):

Update the gradle script of your module. Under the Gradle Scripts, the file is shown as build.gradle (Module : app). Not the build.gradle (Project : nameofproject)

this is an example of gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.project"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
```

change the minSdkVersion, to the desired one.

sync gradle and clean your project.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade your build.gradle file by changing minSdkVersion to whatever version you want: for e.g minSdkVersion 18