# Android P app not installing on KitKat

Tags: android, android-studio, android-9.0-pie

I recently installed android Studio 3.2 Canary 14 for developing for Android P. My minSDK is 15, target is 'P' but running app on Kitkat fails with error

> Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_OLDER_SDK]
>   Installation failed since app's minSdkVersion is newer than device's API level (API 19).
>   Please update your apps minSdkVersion.
>   Error while Installing APK

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing API level Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19465049/changing-api-level-android-studio)

Answer (score 2):

Google sets it up such that apps compiled against `android-P` can only run on Android P devices, until we exit the developer previews later this year. The build tools override your `minSdkVersion` and give it a value of `P`. You may be able to see this in the "Merged Manifest" tab in Android Studio.

Comment: @CommonsWare, can prevent the build tools from overriding minSdkVersion? It happens to me when I try to compile against android-Q while trying to run it on android P.

Comment: @Keselme: Not until Beta 4, due out in early June. At that point, the build tools should support the real API level (29), and normal `minSdkVersion` behavior should resume.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Just make Your **`compileSdkVersion 'android-P'`**

and Your **`targetSdkVersion 27`** it will work