# The program on android studio does not run on old devices (android 6 and below), is there a function to specify the minimum version?,

Tags: java, android

i wrote an application on Android Studio, news feed on firebase from google (i'm beginner in Android). The program works fine, but only on the lastest versions of Android. Is there a function to indicate the version (in the code i used ViewPager, TableLayout,, maybe they only work on new devices?)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing API level Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19465049/changing-api-level-android-studio)

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a function to indicate the version

This is controlled by `minSdkVersion`, set in your app module's `build.gradle` file (e.g., `app/build.gradle` for a typical Android Studio starter project).

> in the code i used ViewPager, TableLayout,, maybe they only work on new devices?

`TableLayout` has existed since Android 1.0. `ViewPager` works back to Android 4.0.

Comment: minSdkVersion -> 15

Comment: targetSdkVersion -> 29

Comment: @MbProger: So, your app is advertising that it supports Android 4.0 and higher. If you want to support fewer Android versions than that, raise the `minSdkVersion` to a higher level. The [distribution dashboards](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/) will help you determine how popular older versions of Android are.

Answer (score 0):

In the build.gradle file under the android section there is a field named `compileSdkVersion`, change it to change the minimum API

Comment: `compileSdkVersion` does not affect the minimum API level that the app can run on.