# i have a problem when i try to build mergeExtDexDebug

Tags: java, android, gradle

i have tried to clean or rebuild project but same problem so idon't know how to fix it
if anyone can told me how to fix it i will appreciate it

error logs :

**mergeDebugResource :**

```
> Task :app:mergeDebugResources FAILED
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource compilation failed","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\GEV\\Desktop\\StrangerRepo\\app\\build\\intermediates\\incremental\\mergeDebugResources\\merged.dir\\values-h???dp-land-v13\\values-h???dp-land-v13.xml"}],"original":"C:\\Users\\GEV\\Desktop\\StrangerRepo\\app\\build\\intermediates\\incremental\\mergeDebugResources\\merged.dir\\values-h???dp-land-v13\\values-h???dp-land-v13.xml: AAPT: error: invalid configuration 'h???dp-land-v13'.\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource compilation failed","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\GEV\\Desktop\\StrangerRepo\\app\\build\\intermediates\\incremental\\mergeDebugResources\\merged.dir\\values-w???dp-land-v13\\values-w???dp-land-v13.xml"}],"original":"C:\\Users\\GEV\\Desktop\\StrangerRepo\\app\\build\\intermediates\\incremental\\mergeDebugResources\\merged.dir\\values-w???dp-land-v13\\values-w???dp-land-v13.xml: AAPT: error: invalid configuration 'w???dp-land-v13'.\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource compilation failed","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\GEV\\Desktop\\StrangerRepo\\app\\build\\intermediates\\incremental\\mergeDebugResources\\merged.dir\\values-h???dp-port-v13\\values-h???dp-port-v13.xml"}],"original":"C:\\Users\\GEV\\Desktop\\StrangerRepo\\app\\build\\intermediates\\incremental\\mergeDebugResources\\merged.dir\\values-h???dp-port-v13\\values-h???dp-port-v13.xml: AAPT: error: invalid configuration 'h???dp-port-v13'.\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource compilation failed","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\GEV\\Desktop\\StrangerRepo\\app\\build\\intermediates\\incremental\\mergeDebugResources\\merged.dir\\values-h???dp-v13\\values-h???dp-v13.xml"}],"original":"C:\\Users\\GEV\\Desktop\\StrangerRepo\\app\\build\\intermediates\\incremental\\mergeDebugResources\\merged.dir\\values-h???dp-v13\\values-h???dp-v13.xml: AAPT: error: invalid configuration 'h???dp-v13'.\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource compilation failed","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\GEV\\Desktop\\StrangerRepo\\app\\build\\intermediates\\incremental\\mergeDebugResources\\merged.dir\\values-h???dp-port-v13\\values-h???dp-port-v13.xml"}],"original":"C:\\Users\\GEV\\Desktop\\StrangerRepo\\app\\build\\intermediates\\incremental\\mergeDebugResources\\merged.dir\\values-h???dp-port-v13\\values-h???dp-port-v13.xml: AAPT: error: invalid configuration 'h???dp-port-v13'.\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource compilation failed","sources":[{"file":"C:\\Users\\GEV\\Desktop\\StrangerRepo\\app\\build\\intermediates\\incremental\\mergeDebugResources\\merged.dir\\values-w???dp-land-v13\\values-w???dp-land-v13.xml"}],"original":"C:\\Users\\GEV\\Desktop\\StrangerRepo\\app\\build\\intermediates\\incremental\\mergeDebugResources\\merged.dir\\values-w???dp-land-v13\\values-w???dp-land-v13.xml: AAPT: error: invalid configuration 'w???dp-land-v13'.\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}

Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> Multiple task action failures occurred:
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
      > Android resource compilation failed
        C:\Users\GEV\Desktop\StrangerRepo\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values-h???dp-land-v13\values-h???dp-land-v13.xml: AAPT: error: invalid configuration 'h???dp-land-v13'.

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

**mergeExtDexDebug:**

```
> Task :app:mergeExtDexDebug
AGPBI: {"kind":"warning","text":"An API level of 31 is not supported by this compiler. Please use an API level of 30 or earlier","sources":[{}],"tool":"D8"}
An API level of 31 is not supported by this compiler. Please use an API level of 30 or earlier
```

anyone can help me please?

Comment: is this solve your problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19465049/changing-api-level-android-studio ?

Comment: No , i tried to upgrade gradle to last version and it works now