# Android Studio-Generate Signed APK Errors

Tags: android, android-studio, apk, generate

I recently started Androids Studio, I bought a quiz game and I tried to modify it a bit with the help of some tutorials, only when I want to generate the apk I get some errors, I tried to do everything from the beginning about 10 times and the same, I don't know where I'm wrong, you have below a link with a video with the errors. Thank you in advance!!!
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=59fxv4F5DYE

Comment: I would recommend to add the exact pieces of code instead of a URL to a youtube video.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are getting an error due to using **Vector drawables** which are supported on Android API 21 and above and your **minSdk** is lower than 21. The solution to this is either update your **[minSdk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54285146/15106139)** version to be at least 21.

Or in your **gradle.build**:

```
android {  
    defaultConfig {  
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true  
    }  
}
```

And in application class define this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);
}
```

And when using the resource for example in your ImageView:

```
<ImageView
     ...
     app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_some_vector" />
```

Comment: Thankss maaaan, you are my hero